# PhP + MySql help needed

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have task to add messages to database using php + mysql.
I created form in html and created php script, but nothing works. It is redirecting me to php file, I don't see anything only blank page .Inn address line

> localhost/twitter/lib/addTweet.php

I haven't any changes in my database table.
Please , help me resolve my problem. Thank you.

HTML

```
<form action="lib/addTweet.php" method="post">
            <textarea class="m_twitt"  name="t_message" placeholder=" Write your twitt there."/></textarea><br>
            <input class="fright" type="submit" name="addTweet" value="Add"/>
        </form>
```

PhP

```
<?
session_start();
include "connect.php";
if(!empty($_POST['t_message'])){
    if(isset($_POST['addTweet'])){
        $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
        $tweet = $_POST['t_message'];
       // $curTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `111212_tweets` (`user_id`,`text`,`pubdate`) VALUES ('$userId','$tweet','$curTime')",$connect) ;
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `111212_tweets` (`user_id`,`text`) VALUES ('$userId', '$tweet'");

        if (!$query){
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }else{
            header('Location: ../main.php');
        }

    }
}else{
//    header('Location: ../index.php');
    echo 'KOLOBOK';
}
```

Comment: could you paste the content of the file "connect.php" ?

Comment: <?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('tweeter');
?>

Comment: And just because no one's mentioned deprecated methods... http://bit.ly/1dFCkWP ... or sql injection and prepared statements... http://bit.ly/19sv0Pb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced `"`. The correct query should be like this

```
("INSERT INTO `111212_tweets` (`user_id`,`text`) VALUES ('$userId', '$tweet')")
```

and

```
<?php ?>// you missed the php in your code
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['addTweet'])` might be empty

Comment: use echo inside `if(isset($_POST['addTweet']))` and check whether it is called or not

Comment: Oh my god!  Thank you ! I'm idiot , missed <?php    , It's working correctly right now.

Comment: Edited my answer. just pointed out the error in the OP's code

Answer (score 0):

If your addTweet.php and html page are in same directory or same page then

```
<form action="addTweet.php" method="post">
```

because you were doing **action="lib/addTweet.php"** so that means it was submiting to addTweet.php which is placed in lib folder in which your current html page is.

Another thing i see in your code is not adding **ending bracket ")"** in your query.

```
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `111212_tweets` (`user_id`,`text`) VALUES ('$userId', '$tweet');");
```

It's a suggestion, let us know if this was going wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I just missed <?php